# Need simple version control tool for own development project (site)

Tags: version-control, dreamweaver

I am doing a project in my spare time, and I need version control. Mainly I need some kind of sync that keeps remote / local files synced up since I make changes both on the server and locally.

Environment is Windows 8, 64bit, main dev tool is Dreamweaver, and the servers are on the host at the moment (although I am thinking for setting up a local db and server).

I don't want anything fancy, or complicated and only this very basic functionality is needed. Just for it to keep track of whether the server version and the local version is most recent, possible warn me if I am about to make a version control mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You say that you need *"some kind of sync that keeps remote / local files synced up"* with simple workflow. Take a closer look at [Apache Subversion (SVN)](http://subversion.apache.org/) then; SVN is a storage and a time machine for your sources and is a great solution to organize your code and development process. Read [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/)!

[Adobe Dreamweaver supports SVN out-of-the-box](http://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/kb/subversion-resources-dreamweaver-cs4-cs5.html), BTW. There is a good article series about using Dreamweaver with SVN:

- [Using Subversion with Dreamweaver CS5 – Part 1: Introducing Subversion](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/using_subversion_pt1.html),
- [Using Subversion with Adobe Dreamweaver CS5 – Part 2: Configuring Dreamweaver to use Subversion](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/using_subversion_pt2.html).

Comment: Thanks bahrep. I didn't think Dreamweaver was very good at version control (it's quite slow, and it tried to sync files that I knew hadn't been changed.) But that was the built-in sync. Maybe if I hook it up with Subversion it will start behaving. I guess that's plenty to go on and I assume you know what you are talking about, so I'll go with this answer :)